# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-state

**Expected**
to get data one time

How do I prevent the following error:

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

I just changed a class based component to functional component and its not working

My source code

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// core components
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";

import { db } from "../../firebase";
export default function TableList() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([])
  var users = []
  db.collection("users").get().then((snapshot)=>{ 
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data =doc.data()
      users.push(data)

    })
  })
  setstate(users)
  console.log(state)

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Card plain>
          <CardHeader plain color="primary">
            <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>
              Users
            </h4>
            <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
              Here is a subtitle for this table
            </p>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Table
              tableHeaderColor="primary"
              tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Country", "City", "Salary"]}
              tableData={[
                ["1", 
                "Dakota Rice", 
                "$36,738", 
                "Niger", 
                "Oud-Turnhout"
                ]
              ]}
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get into a inifnite loop because you change the state while the component gets rendered so that triggers a othe reredner that changes the state and so on to inifnity. To resolve your problem put your state change into a `useEffect`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// core components
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";

import { db } from "../../firebase";
export default function TableList() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var users = [];
    db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push(data);
        });
      });
    setstate(users);
    console.log(state);
  }, []);

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}></GridItem>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Card plain>
          <CardHeader plain color="primary">
            <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Users</h4>
            <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
              Here is a subtitle for this table
            </p>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Table
              tableHeaderColor="primary"
              tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Country", "City", "Salary"]}
              tableData={[
                ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger", "Oud-Turnhout"],
              ]}
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

This part `}, []);` with the empty array at the end of the `useEffect` says to it to run only when the component is rendered the first time. If you want the code in the `useEffect` to be called also on other changes put some values in that array. Each time those values change the `useEffect` will be called. Because we have an empty array the `useEffect` will be called only once.